# Custom property Visio - VBA

Tags: vba, add-in, visio, custom-properties

First of all, I'm a newbie in VBA, and I'm trying to write some scripts for existing Visio document for automation purposes.

I see that my Visio file has objects with custom properties, and I want to play with those custom properties. (I know that seperate add-in is written for custom properties.)

Here I took a screenshot in my Visio file to show how Custom properties menu look like. This menu is accessed via custom add-in in Visio file.

[image]

Based on research, I wrote a simple macro as you see below.
For testing purposes I added shp.Name which works fine but shp.CellsU("Prop.Type").ResultStr("") fails.

I want to access and update custom properties of my shape as you see above.

My script file:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim doc As Visio.Document
    Dim pge As Visio.Page
    Dim shp As Visio.Shape
       
    For Each doc In Application.Documents
        'Debug.Print "* " & doc.Name
        For Each pge In doc.Pages
            'Debug.Print "....s* " & pge.Name
            If pge = "134-1" Then
                For Each shp In pge.Shapes
                    Debug.Print "........* " & shp.Name
                    Debug.Print "........* " & shp.CellsU("Prop.Type").ResultStr("") 
                Next shp   
            End If      
       Next pge
    Next doc
End Sub
```

If you help me with these, I would be appreciated!

Comment: Is **Prop.Type** exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your picture we can see properties **Labels** (1st row), not their real **Names** (2nd row) !
[image: Names vs Labels]
Please check property **Name**!